# How to calculating percent max drawdown likes Tradingview Strategy report?

Tags: pine-script

I want to get the percent of maxdrawdown like the Tradingview strategy report?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
strategy.max_drawdown*100/strategy.initial_capital
```

Comment: Not correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

strategy.max_drawdown*100/strategy.initial_capital, This is not right.Because the maximum drawdown amount and the maximum drawdown percentage are not necessarily the same. My initial capital is 10,000. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TATbe.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).